# Undefined is not a function - RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having trouble including a module in RequireJS.

There's two files..  test.js and card.js

In test.js, when the page loads it says "undefined is not a function":

```
require(
    ['app', 
     'jquery', 
     'card'], 
    function(App, $, Card) {
        var card = new Card("test");
    }
);
```

Here is the card.js:

```
define("Card", function () {
    function Card(name) {
       this.name = name;             
    };

    return Card;
});
```

I put some console.log()'s in the card.js and it calls those fine when it's being referenced like that in test.js.  Also if I were to define a regular js object class in card.js (e.g.):

```
function Card(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
```

I am able to create that Card object properly in test.js.

Any clues how I'm hooking it all up wrong?

Comment: Click on the link at the right of the "undefined..." message in your inspector, it will show you the line it is breaking at.

Comment: It is breaking at this line: var card = new Card("test");

Comment: Well, then you're obviously **not** "*able to create that Card object properly*".

Comment: Hint: your module names are not the same. Not sure whether require handles them case-insensitive and why it does not grump about that.

Comment: I was able to create a card object, just not through modules.  It turned out to be a case sensitivity issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) said, is that your module names are not the same.

To RequireJS, `Card` and `card` are different modules.

All you have to do is change `card.js` to

```
define("card", function () {
    function Card(name) {
       this.name = name;             
    };

    return Card;
});
```